# Sublime Text 2 search and replace multiple words

Tags: find-and-replace, sublime-text-2

I want to replace multiple words using regex in just one search accross all files. Something like this:

Find: (dyspnea)|(jugular_swelling)
Replace: (dispnea)|(turgencia_jugular)

And this would replace all dyspnea to dispnea, and jugular_swelling to turgencia_jugular.

Is this possible?